# Removing all the characters from a given string

Tags: java, string, data-structures, replace, time-complexity

how can I modify my code so that it removes all the characters in a given string (not just a string) in another string in `O(n)`? If using other data structures would help, please hint as well.

```
public static String removeChar(String s, char ch){
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    char[] charArray= s.toCharArray();
    for (int i=0; i<charArray.length; i++){
        if (charArray[i]!=ch) {
            sb.append(charArray[i]);
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Is there a faster way for this?

UPDATE: I want to write a new function like `removeAllCharsInSecondStringFromFirstString(String S1, String S2)`

Comment: Do you have to implement it yourself? `newStr = origStr.replaceAll("[abcde]*", "")` looks pretty tempting to me...

Comment: I prefer to implement it myself to practice yeah. I have seen `replaceAll`

Comment: Guava's [`CharMatcher`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) class is excellent for this sort of thing, as well.

Comment: from my understanding, you will have to match each character of the first string against each character in the second string, which will always lead to `O(n*m)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With hints and help of dimo I wrote this solution:

```
public static String removeAllChars(String src, String dst){
    HashSet<Character> chars = new HashSet<>();
    char[] dstCharArray=dst.toCharArray();
    for (int i=0; i<dstCharArray.length; i++){
        chars.add(dstCharArray[i]);
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] srcCharArray = src.toCharArray();
    for (int i=0; i<srcCharArray.length; i++){
        if (!chars.contains(srcCharArray[i])){
            sb.append(srcCharArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();

}
```

Comment: Nice job! You may find it more clear or straightforward to skip the fancy Java classes and simple use an array. You can refer to my answer for more information.

Comment: Note that you don't need to construct a `char[]` in order to loop over the characters in `String`. You can use `String.charAt(i)` to get the `char` at index `i` without needing to construct a separate `char[]`.

Comment: @dimo414 why would you use HashMap over HashSet?

Comment: @MonaJalal that was a typo. I would use a `HashSet` for O(1) `.contains()` checks.

Answer (score 2):

Rather then iterating each character of the `String`, you could use [`String.indexOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) and a loop to add each substring between `ch` intervals. Something like,

```
public static String removeChar(String s, char ch) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int p1 = 0, p2 = s.indexOf(ch);
    while (p2 > -1) {
        sb.append(s.substring(p1, p2));
        p1 = p2 + 1;
        p2 = s.indexOf(ch, p1);
    }
    if (p1 < s.length()) {
        sb.append(s.substring(p1, s.length()));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: well, I want to change the function to `removeAllCharsInSecondStringFromFirstString(String S1, String S2)`

Comment: [`String.indexOf(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-) and `p1 = p2 + s2.length();` Next time, include all of the relevant details in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to implement this yourself you can use a `Set` to contain the collection of characters that you want to strip out. Here's a template to get you started:

```
public static String removeAllChars(String source, String charsString) {
  HashSet<Character> chars = new HashSet<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < charsString.length(); i++) {
    chars.add(charsString.charAt(i));
  }

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
    // chars.contains(source.charAt(i)) is O(1)
    // use this to determine which chars to exclude
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: would this assure that the order in the source string would not change?

Comment: @MonaJalal Since the loop is traversing the `source` string in order, whatever you add to the `StringBuilder` will be in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this.

Remove all no numerical value

```
String str = "343.dfsdgdffsggdfg333";
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

Output will give you "343.333"

If in the future you will need delete numerical and special value try this

```
String str = "343.dfsdgdffsggdfg333";
string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
```